# How to find indexof value for particular tag/class in Html Document

Tags: java, html, dom

I'm going to parse Html content using DOM parsing.(org.w3c.dom java). I'll recursively parse the given html content by processing its child node. Also I'll check if particular node is div tag with class name "depth"(for example). If it so i want starting indexof value of that div tag. Is there any way to find the name?

Please help.

Html content:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">
This is content inside div tag with id as one
<div class="depth">
This is node i'm searching for
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result:

> index  :  91

Comment: Just sample index value for above html content. I counted the character and put the number as 91. I don't know i have calculated correctly.

Comment: "check if particular node is div tag with class name "depth"(for example)" if this is all what you want to do, you can consider using JSOUP.  http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: please try: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: @Sridhar I don't how selector-syntax will work. Can you explain briefly

Comment: @Roshan Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").get();                                                       
Elements depthDivs = doc.select("div.depth");

depthDivs will be collection of divs with depth css class

Comment: @Sridhar This will return only element list not indexof value. I want indexof value.